# Jetpack Compose: How to pass values to composables in the tree?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'am using Compose now with passing parameters to functions, but I feel, those parameters are getting longer with each new data to be passed down the tree.

I am wondering if there is a way to pass values to other composables down the tree.

Comment: You can use MVVM class to store variable there and instantiate MVVM in each required function, whether it is in another file or in same. Don't worry MVVM instance just create once in the memory

Answer (score 7):

Other than using function arguments for Composables (the recommended way),
you can use [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal):
*Avoid CompositionLocal for concepts that aren't thought as tree-scoped or sub-hierarchy scoped.*

First, define variable of `compositionLocalOf`  globally (e.g., in *LocalCompositions.kt*):

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.compositionLocalOf

data class Post(val title: String)
val LocalPost = compositionLocalOf { Post(title = "Ahmed") }
```

and then define it inside `@Compose` function to be used by other composables down the tree:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainView() {
  ...
  val post = Post(title = "Shamil")

  CompositionLocalProvider(LocalPost provides post) {
    PostContentView()
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, retrieve the value inside a `@Composable`:

```
// composable down the nodes tree
@Composable
fun PostContentView() {
  ...
  val post = LocalPost.current
  ...
}
```

##### Observe variable changes

If you want to achieve the above solution but with watching changes to the variable and update the composable (node) accordingly, you can use [`MutableState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/MutableState) variable.

Redefining the previous example:

*LocalCompositions.kt*:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.compositionLocalOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.compositionLocalOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf

data class Post(val title: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf(""))
val LocalPost = compositionLocalOf { Post(title = mutableStateOf("Ahmed")) }
```

and then define it inside `@Compose` function to be used by other composables down the tree:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainView() {
  ...
  val post = Post(title = remember { mutableStateOf("Shamil") })

  CompositionLocalProvider(LocalPost provides post) {
    PostContentView()
  }
  ...

  post.title.value = "Ali"

  ...
}
```

Now, retrieve the value inside a `@Composable`:

```kotlin
// composable down the nodes tree
@Composable
fun PostContentView() {
  ...
  val post = LocalPost.current

  // now this composable will be updated whenever post.title value is updated

  if (post.title.value == "Jamal") {
   ...
  } 

  ...
}
```

Comment: CompositionLocal should be thought of like ThreadLocal or Globals - they create implicit data dependencies and implicit API contracts that break modularity and make your code much less maintainable.  You should feel bad every time you use it, prefer passing parameters explicitly.

https://twitter.com/JimSproch/status/1395801409229033478
https://twitter.com/JimSproch/status/1366086566867701760

Comment: @JIm first thanks a lot for your reply.
i use it to avoid having lots of function parameters to be passed down the node tree. for me, it is just to see my code as minimal and cleaner as possible.
i am using to for an explicit purpose: passing data to the nodes tree, and as noted from the official docs of *Locally scoped data with CompositionLocal*: **Avoid CompositionLocal for concepts that aren't thought as tree-scoped or sub-hierarchy scoped.**

Comment: You and I have discussed via twitter, adding context here for those following along at home...

CompositionLocals are inherently implicit data dependencies.  If you are using a CompositionLocal, it is by definition not explicit.

That highlighted sentence specifically calls out when to absolutely NOT use CompositionLocals.  It does NOT say you SHOULD CompositionLocals for all tree-scoped or hierarchy-scoped fields, only that it is a potential use.  They should generally be avoided for virtually all intents and purposes for the reasons previously mentioned.

Comment: @JIm please update the official docs to avoid bad practices to beginners like me or make writing Compose code clean.
your rough discussion on Twitter:
https://twitter.com/jimsproch/status/1430558312978739200?s=21

Comment: This was really useful in my project. Now I can easly use "global" data over the application.